# What do I have to do, so the program would output 1 and 0 instead of true and false?

Tags: java, math, output, logical-operators

While practicing Java, I came up with a `Truth Table` program for logical operators. 
Now, I can't figure out how to display 1 and 0 instead of true and false.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean p, q;
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
        p = true; q = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
        p = true; q = false;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
        p = false; q = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

        p = false; q = false;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
    }

}
```

Comment: you can transform your booleans using `p ? 1 : 0`

Comment: You should define a method `printRow(boolean p, boolean q)`, so you're not repeating yourself four times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of below lines:

```
System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
```

You can do as below

```
print(p,q);
print(p&q, p|q);
print(p^q, !p);

private void print(boolean left, boolean right)
{
    System.out.println((left?1:0) + "\t" + (right?1:0))
}
```

Comment: As these three lines seem to be allways the same, i´d put all three prints in in the method and just call it with `print(p,q)` to redurce the written code a bit more. Or create another method with all three `print` calls who just call this method three times.

Comment: Yes, agree. that will reduce the `loc`.

Comment: The division of the lines in OP's code is completely arbitrary. I'd just do `System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s%n", f(p), f(q), f(p && q), f(p || q), f(p ^ q), f(!p));`, where `f` is the function mapping boolean to `{0,1}`.